# Looping in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape some elements and get updates every 15mins but i don't know how to do a loop in this:

```
const totalCases = await page.$eval('.maincounter-number span', element => element.innerHTML);

await page1.type('[class="_39LWd"]', totalCases);
await page1.keyboard.press('Enter');
```

Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Just loop it inside `setInterval`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already solved.
used:

```
while (loop) {
        if (loop = 1) {

            const totalCases = await page.$eval('.maincounter-number span', element => element.innerHTML);

            await page1.type('[class="_39LWd"]', 'Casos totais: '+ totalCases);
            await page1.keyboard.press('Enter');
            await page1.waitFor(900000);
            await page.reload();
        }
    }
```